# how to get the coordinates of an image on MapControl

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I have xaml:

```
<maps:MapControl>
...
  <maps:MapItemsControl>
    <Image
      ...
      maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding MYLocation}"
      maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="0.5,0.5"
       />
   </maps:MapItemsControl>
 </maps:MapControl>
```

When i try get geolocation in code, i have problem. 
C#:

```
var child = ((MapItemsControl)(this.map.Children[0])).Items[0];
var coordinate = MapControl.GetLocation(child);
```

But coordinate=null, How do I get the coordinates of the image?

Comment: problems happen on the Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 1):

Just run into this one as well. Tested after assignment and it's still null. Looks like GetLocation just doesn't return correctly.

```
MapControl.SetLocation(iconStart, pushpinToAdd.pinPoint);
MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(iconStart, new Point(0.5, 1));
Geopoint geopoint = MapControl.GetLocation(iconStart);
Debug.WriteLine(geopoint.Position.Latitude + "," + geopoint.Position.Longitude);
```

Causes it to crash with NullReferenceException. Tested on both phone and emulator. Really quite bad.

As a solution, going to use a Tag with an id in to then reference my data and pull back the coords from there.

Good luck

---

Edit:

Ended up setting up a tapped event listener on my pin, with that could do

```
 private async void Pin_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Geopoint geopoint = null;
     MainMap.GetLocationFromOffset(e.GetPosition(MainMap), out geopoint);
     Debug.WriteLine(geopoint.Position.Latitude + "," + geopoint.Position.Longitude);
 }
```